# Cannot read property of undefined, but it is defined

Tags: reactjs, mount

I have this componentDidMount function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { insurances } = this.props;
    const insuranceId = this.props.match.params.id;

    const insurance = insurances.find(insurance => insurance.id == insuranceId);

    this.setState({ insurance: insurance }, () => {
      console.log("insurance", this.state.insurance.tip); <--- this is what i am talking about
    });
  }
```

That `console.log()` returns an object. But if i change it to `console.log(this.state.insurance.tip)` which is one of the properties, I get the error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'tip' of undefined**. I don't really understand how mounting works. Could it be because it is not mounted? If so, how do i fix it?

**EDIT**

console.log('insurance', insurance), before setState is corect:

```
id: 1, user_id: 1, tip: "Asigurare", date_exp: "1974-10-14", date_notif: "1975-10-03", …}
created_at: "2019-03-15 10:54:40"
date_exp: "1974-10-14"
date_notif: "1975-10-03"
id: 1
note: "Nam id ipsam sequi."
tip: "Asigurare"
updated_at: "2019-03-15 10:54:40"
user_id: 1
```

but if I do `console.log(this.state.insurance)` returns an object with undefined properties

**EDIT 2**
I think this is close to what i have https://codesandbox.io/s/n72rx0k660

Comment: You are passing a callback function in `this.setState`, but you still use `this.state`. The new state is provided as first argument. You can try this as callback: `(state) => console.log(state.insurance.tip)`

Comment: can you `console.log` the out `insurance` prior to the `setState` being called to verify it's being set properly? if your `insurance` isn't set, you are still setting the state to be an object of `{ insurance: undefined}`

Comment: i edited the answer so it is easier to read

Comment: That's very odd. Consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: what @Tholle said. Can you provide a codesandbox version or something that's like your code to see what's happening? I made a quick demo poking around to verify the `setState` callback works as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/98346oyx6r You can see that in console, the callback function logs out `this.state` and it is accurate to the freshest state. The only conclusion that I can draw is that your insurance object is not defined when you set state...

Comment: I think this is close to what i have:  https://codesandbox.io/s/n72rx0k660

Answer (score 0):

The way you have defined your state is the issue.

You have it as

```
state = {
 insurance: [
   {
    tip: "1"
   }
 ]
};
```

Change it to :

```
state = {
insurance:
  {
    tip: "1"
  }
};
```

For you to access it as this.state.insurance.tip it needs to be a key in the insurance **object**. What you have right now it this.state.insurance[0].tip
Since insurance is an array right now.

lmk if this needs more clarification.